# Entering a User's Contacts on Mobile Browsers in HTML5 WebApp

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, mobile

We need our users to enter a handful of their contacts (name, phone, email) into our mobile webapp (HTML5).  We would like a better way than requiring them to type all of this information one by one into form fields for each contact on their mobile device, which would be sufficiently tedious that many people wouldn't do it.  In Cordova, it is possible to access the user's contacts data in their phone (with their permission) using a plugin in order to automate this.  Is there a way for users to enter contact info in a webapp (non-Cordova, HTML5-only) that is superior to having the user type them all on their mobile device?  As far as we know, using FB login wouldn't be a good option since we are primarily trying to have them enter their contacts phone number.  This webapp functionality needs to run on mobile Safari and mobile Chrome at a minimum, but needn't necessarily be compatible with every potential browser.

Thanks

PS, We already realize why giving 'every app' access to the user's address book isn't allowed by browsers...